# How is type information stored in memory (if at all)

Tags: java, c, memory, types, jvm

I know how C-style languages store the data in a variable. They use one or two blocks on the stack, and in the case of objects space is also allocated on the heap, for its fields. But where does java store whether two blocks make a double or an int? How does it know that a particular object reference in the stack points to an object.

The thought that spawned this question is what happens if I do

```
String s;
```

If I understand correctly, this creates an object reference in the stack that is set to null, so two bytes of zeros, and no corresponding space on the heap. If so, how does Java "remember" that this reference belongs to a String?

I can imagine that remembering types isn't necessary, and the bytecode just operates on raw data, and we know it does so correctly, because it compiles. On the other hand, that sounds like type erasure, which leads to lots of corner cases and unsafety. If this is the case, why is the type erasure on generics different from type erasure on the primitives and objects themselves? (ie. for the latter, you never ever have to think about it, and with generics it crops up all the time).

**NB: I say C-style, because I assume the solution is the same for all languages in that family. If there are different approaches, I'd like to know about the differences as well.**

Comment: C-Style doesn't mean C-style memory management. You can't equate C-Style syntax with C-style memory management.

Comment: @VaibhavRaj, fair enough, but I assumed that most of them solve this problem in the same way...

Comment: To the voters: please comment when you downvote. I'd like to know what makes this question ill-posed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `String s` is

- a variable inside a method, the bytecode is compiled with the knowledge that that reference is a `String`.
- a variable in a class, static or non-static, then the class definition includes the knowledge that that field holds a `String`, though that's almost never used -- it's not really necessary.
- Each object in Java has a few bytes allocated that refer to its own type.  (This is *not* stored in the reference -- it's stored in the object itself.)

Comment: So if I read your answer correctly, it's stored in the surrounding class (if there is one) and in the object (if the reference is non-null). If s is inside a method, and the reference is null, Am I right in saying that the information that the reference is a String is erased? It can only be inferred from the way the bytecode treats that bit of data?

Comment: Not quite; the bytecode does preserve the type of each local variable in the stack frame for the method.

Answer (score 0):

When you do this:

```
String s;
```

In Java, it doesn't occupy the heap, it only keeps data of its type in the ***`bytecode`***, if to associate to it with heap object of the same type later on.

The heap is occupied once `new` keyword is used explicitly (or used implicitly in case of `String`, you can look at it [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/strings.html) ).

```
String s = "foo"; // or 
String s = new String("foo"); // or

MyObject myObject = new MyObject();
                     ^
                     |_ _ _ _ Right here
```

Check [this](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2076614/core-java/object-initialization-in-java.html) out.

Comment: That's not really an answer. As I noted in my question, I know it only creates a reference on the stack, and nothing in the heap (unless s is a field, in which case the reference _does_ exist in the stack). My question is about where the type information is stored.

Comment: Well, actually it keeps data of its type in the bytecode, if to associate to it with heap object of the same type later on.